# Retrieve method names from Visual Studio Team Services Project Collection

Tags: rest, team-foundation-server

I am a relatively new user to the Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) platform and I wondered if it is possible to pull a list of methods/classes/functions etc. I have created from the projects within my account.

The best answer I have found so far seems to be this:

https://writeabout.net/2016/06/17/get-a-list-of-all-releases-in-tfs-or-visual-studio-team-services/

Which directed me to the following Microsoft page:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics

Does anyone know if what I want to do is even possible using this REST API?

Obviously because it is my account I can clone all the projects to my local drive and perhaps use the "Find in Files" function in something like Notepad++ to search for "Sub" or "void" etc. in the relevant file extensions but that seems like a lot of effort.

The reason for the question is that I have a growing library of projects stored there and I have noticed that I am beginning to create very similar classes/methods and figure I need to think about a centralised library of "Standard methods" so I don't repeat work I have already done.

Failing the VSTS ProjectCollection -> List route, can anyone recommend a better approach to the problem as I have described it?

Thanks in advance!

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others who might be wondering the same thing, I recently re-discovered the Hound application available here: [Hound by etsy](https://github.com/etsy/hound). I say re-discovered because I had set it up before but only on my local machine.

I found out that you can point the tool at any .git link that VSTS creates and pull those methods/classes into the database.

Here is my current config.json file for those that are interested:

```
{
"max-concurrent-indexers" : 2,
"dbpath" : "data",
"repos" : {
    "Create Assembly From Excel Addin" : {
        "url" : "https://github.com/AlexFielder/CreateAssemblyFromExcelAddin.git"
    },
    "Directory Parser For Inventor iLogic" : {
        "url" : "https://github.com/AlexFielder/DirectoryParserForInventoriLogic.git",
        "ms-between-poll": 10000,
        "exclude-dot-files": true
    },
    "Vault - Four Eyes Principle" : {
        "url" : "file:///C:/_VS_Backup/Graitec/Vault - Four Eyes Principle"
    },
    "Batch Print Windows 7" : {
        "url" : "file:///C:/_VS_Backup/Graitec/batchprintwin7"
    },
    "BrepToolkit" : {
        "url" : "file:///C:/_VS_Backup/Graitec/BrepToolkit"
    },
    "letsencrypt-win-simple" : {
        "url" : "file:///C:/_VS_Backup/Graitec/letsencrypt-win-simple"
    },
    "Power Pack github" : {
        "url" : "https://alexfielder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Power%20Pack%20For%20Inventor%20AddIn"
    },
    "Excel Stream Dynamic" : {
        "url" : "file:///C:/_VS_Backup/CH2M Hill/ExcelStreamDynamic"
    },
    "Ribbon Commands" : {
        "url" : "file:///C:/_VS_Backup/CH2M Hill/NewRibbonCmds"
    },
    "Query Vault" : {
        "url" : "https://github.com/AlexFielder/QueryVault.git"
    },
    "iLogic github" : {
        "url" : "https://github.com/AlexFielder/iLogic.git"
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,

Alex.